# How to set datepickerOptions in daterangepicker to set default date

Tags: daterangepicker

I want to set Default date in regional format to dateRangePicker . But having trouble in settting it.

Answer (score -1):

Click on given link and read it's documentation carefully.
http://glad.github.io/glDatePicker/#examples

Hopefully, You will able to get resolve.